# Trigonometric identities for Bessel Functions?

Tags: trigonometry, bessel-functions

I'm wondering if there exists extensions of trigonometric identities to special functions like Bessel?

For example, is there an alternative way to express the following?

$J_0((a+b)x) = ?$

Thanks

Comment: See identities $(67)$ and $(68)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

Comment: Not as elegant as I'd hoped. Thanks!